# How can I perform a SQL 'NOT IN' query faster?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table (EMAIL) of email addresses:

```
EmailAddress
------------
jack@aol.com
jill@aol.com
tom@aol.com
bill@aol.lcom
```

and a table (BLACKLIST) of blacklisted email addresses:

```
EmailAddress
------------
jack@aol.com
jill@aol.com
```

and I want to select those email addresses that are in the EMAIL table but NOT in the BLACKLIST table.  I'm doing:

```
SELECT EmailAddress
FROM EMAIL
WHERE EmailAddress NOT IN
   (
      SELECT EmailAddress
      FROM BLACKLIST
   )
```

but when the row counts get very high the performance is terrible.

How can I better do this?  *(Assume generic SQL if possible.  If not, assume T-SQL.)*

Comment: Add index on BLACKLIST..EmailAddress column to improve performance of eventually chosen query.

Comment: @Tomek - I should have indicated, the performance problems are with the index included.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use a left outer join, or a `not exists` clause.

Left outer join:

```
select E.EmailAddress
  from EMAIL E left outer join BLACKLIST B on (E.EmailAddress = B.EmailAddress)
 where B.EmailAddress is null;
```

Not Exists:

```
select E.EmailAddress
  from EMAIL E where not exists
         (select EmailAddress from BLACKLIST B where B.EmailAddress = E.EmailAddress)
```

**Both** are quite generic SQL solutions (don't depend on a specific DB engine). I would say that the latter is a little bit more performant (not by much though). But definitely more performant than the `not in` one.

As commenters stated, you can also try creating an index on `BLACKLIST(EmailAddress)`, that should help speed up the execution of your query.

Comment: The `not exists` may be faster on some DB engines but AFAIK, SQL Server optimizes that automatically for you and converts the `IN` into `NOT Exists`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I believe the `left join` will be slower and the `not exists` will generate the same query plan as the OP's query.

Comment: @Icarus: thanks! Didn't know that. Will add in the answer that an index on `EmailAddress` column from `BLACKLIST` should also help.

Comment: @Icarus - `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` aren't the same if the column is nullable.  `NOT EXISTS` tends to perform better in SQL Server than LOJ and avoids the issues with NULLs so I prefer it.

Answer (score 4):

NOT IN differs from NOT EXISTS if the blacklist allow null value as EmailAddress. If there is a single null value the result of the query will always return zero rows because NOT IN (null) is unknown / false for every value. The query plans therefore differs slighyly but I don't think there would be any serious performance impact.

A suggestion is to create a new table called VALIDEMAIL, add a trigger to BLACKLIST that removes addresses from VALIDEMAIL when rows are inserted and add to VALIDEMAIL when removed from BLACKLIST. Then replace EMAIL with a view that is a union of both VALIDEMAIL and BLACKLIST.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

This was just a really long-winded way of telling you that, for the pattern of finding all rows in table A where some condition does not exist in table B, NOT EXISTS is typically going to be your best choice. But, as always, you need to test these patterns in your own environment, using your schema, data and hardware, and mixed in with your own workloads.

More Details
https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Answer (score 1):

```
select E.EmailAddress
  from EMAIL E where not exists
         (select EmailAddress from BLACKLIST B where B.EmailAddress = E.EmailAddress)
```

Equals 
(BTW there is probably an owner)

```
select EmailAddress from mail.EMAIL 
EXCEPT
select EmailAddress from mail.BLACKLIST
```

will give you the rows that are different even if NULL in an EmailAddress